# How to write links in SVG to be URL-relative instead of webserver root (Filesystem) relative?

Tags: html, url, svg, hyperlink

When I add a link inside a SVG file, like

```
<a xlink:href="target.htm"></a>
```

then this link is treated as filesystem-relative to where the SVG sits, for example (assuming a  Wordpress setup) it becomes `www.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/mysvgfolder/target.htm`.

When doing this in HTML (sitting in the same filesystem path as the SVG file), like `<a href="target.htm">my Link</a>`, then the link actually gets `www.example.com/prettyurl/target.htm`, no matter what the actual filesystem path is.

How do I have to enter the relative link in the SVG file to actually get (HTTP-)URL-relative links that respect my prettylink structure?

Absolute paths are no option for me, because the SVG files are meant to be used on different domains and in different filesystem paths.

Comment: Absolute URLs are no way for you right?

Comment: @kwoxer Yes, because I write SVG files that should work on several sites and always link relative to themselves (but with regards to the actual URL, not their filesystem path - so, just like regular HTML links behave).

Comment: Why not simply redirect via htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put the domain in you could use

```
<a xlink:href="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/mysvgfolder/target.htm">
```

This will expand to reflect the domain but won't be relative to a file location.

Alternatively use an HTML `<base>` tag and then all relative links will be relative to the `<base>` tag location. You'd need to be careful with internal links if you did that of course.

Comment: But the SVG is supposed to be used in multiple places (and these may not necessarily be under `/wordpress/...` but maybe under `/joomla/...` or under `/mycustompage/...`). What I need is that `<a xlink:href="[something]">` refers relative to the current HTTP-URL (`example.com/games/[something]` for example).

Comment: Addition: Without having to hardcode `example.com/games/` into the SVG, of course. So the question is actually: How to make "SVG-a act like HTML-a"? So that I can move around my SVG without breaking any links (just like it works with HTML files that contain relative links)

Comment: HTML and SVG links work in exactly the same way. If HTML links work then so will SVG links as they are the same thing. Equally if SVG links don't work neither will HTML ones. You need to make the question clearer really as I don't understand what distinction you're trying to draw between HTML and SVG

Comment: On my system (apache 2.4 delivering to Firefox), when I put a file `foo.htm` and a file `foo.svg` in the same server folder (`/var/www/mysite/subfolder`). Both with a link to `target.htm`. And then go to `www.example.com/prettyurl/foo.htm` and hover the link I am lead to `www.example.com/prettyurl/target.htm`. However with `www.example.com/prettyurl/foo.svg` when hovering the link I am lead to `www.example.com/mysite/subfolder/target.htm`. So, obviously they act different at the end user.

Comment: You've screwed up your apache install/configuration then because they both work the same (i.e. as www.example.com/mysite/subfolder/target.htm) for me. Ask on SuperUser how to fix that. Or alternatively you've done something strange in the html file.

Comment: I just found the cause of the problem. For relative HTML links the target URL is created from the pretty URL (just like the user sees in his browser). But for SVG it is actually created from the `data`-path if the SVG is included via `<object data="path/to/svg">`. But since I'm building this `data` string dynamically via PHP before any URL rewrite has happened, the `data` path is obviously the plain filesystem path relative to the webserver root dir. I need to recode this PHP part then. I'll accept yor answer, because in the end, it lead me on the right track. :)